# how can I use functions from custom component in a custom module (Joomla 1.7)?

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, module, components

I am in the process of writing a custom component along with some custom modules in Joomla 1.7 and I am having trouble figuring out how I can use function within my component inside my custom modules.  I don't want to duplicate these functions because there's a very good chance of those getting out of sync when changes are made.

Can I just include a file to get access to those functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shure. You can always do stuff like this inside modules:

```
require_once (JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'components'.DS.'com_mycompo'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'helper.php');
```

and then

```
$settings = & MyHelper::myHelperFunction();
```